# Multi-stage differential amplifier

Tags: amplifier, differential, circuit-design

What is the purpose of combining two differential amplifiers as in the figure below? The first differential amplifier is a single input balanced output and the second differential amplifier is a dual input unbalanced output. What is being achieved here? I understand the purpose of the current mirror.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like with opamps you have a choice of gain versus bandwidth. In the first stage the gain is limited (compared to a solution where there would be a PNP current mirror instead of R1 and R2) but you get more bandwith in return. If you need more gain than this first stage can privode, just add a second stage which is what has been done here. You would't want to maximise the gain of the second stage (and thus limit the bandwidth) so again a resistive load is used instead of a current mirror. Obviously the designer wanted a single-ended output so that is why only Q5 has a load resistor. Giving Q4 a load resistor as well doesn't change much to the overall design.

So: less gain but more bandwith !

Comment: ok ive understood what you have just said. But ive one question. The thing is that im applying zero volt at the base of transistor q2. At the output of q2, im getting a signal which is shifted by a dc constant i.e, signal + X. Why is it that we want this output to be forwarded in the remaining stages instead of the output of q1 which is not grounded and has a signal?

Comment: I sense that you're reasoning: If there's no signal at the base of Q2 then there will be no signal at the output of Q2, and thus no signal across R2. **But that's not true !** Note that the sum of Ic(Q1) + Ic(Q2) must be constant (it is forced constant by the constant current coming out of Q3). So even if we keep the base of Q2 at zero (no signal), a signal at the base of Q1 **will** change the current Ic(Q1) and therefore Ic(Q2) will also change. If Ic(Q1) increases, Ic(Q2) is forced to decrease. So there **is** a signal across R2 !

Comment: And even though you're applying a **single ended signal** at the input (Vid+ = signal, Vid- = ground) we're still getting a differential signal at the output of the first stage. This differential signal can easily be fed straight into a second stage. Try designing a single-ended second stage that can take this signal, you will find that it is much harder to make that work. Differential amplifiers are **much easier** to design and use.

Comment: ok i've tested it and got a signal at the output of the 2nd stage as u said. can i conclude that the first stage is used so as we can get a large range of frequencies and the second stage just amplifier the signal?

Comment: *we can get a large range of frequencies* We call that: the first stage *has a large bandwidth*. No, both stages amplify the signal the signal and both stages need the large bandwith. The bandwith will be limited by the smallest bandwith of any of the individual amplifiers so it is no use to make one having a large and the other having a small bandwith (except when you want to make dominant pole, for example in an amplifier with feedback).

Answer (score 0):

Two-stage or multi-stage amplifiers are used to get higher gain.

The first stage is a differential amplifier with a differential output. The second stage converts this differential output into a single ended output. This is often done if a simple common-emitter or common-source stage follows.

In this case the signal generated by Q4 is not being used, it would be more efficient to use a current mirror to combine it with the signal of Q5.

Comment: if signal generated by q4 is not being used, then i could simply use a common emitter instead of the second differential amplifier. is it correct?

Comment: No, the differential pair has the advantage that you get a proper operating point in the second stage. With a CE-stage the operating point would not be well defined.